# css link color on wordpress with added class

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to edit a theme with the additional CSS options instead of hardcoding things in, but it is proving very difficult.

[This page](http://rymdaret.se/superrymdaret-2019/) has a link on the bottom that is black and I am trying to make it white.

```
<figure class="wp-block-image linktest">
<img src="link" alt="" class="wp-image-119782" srcset="link" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px">
<figcaption><a href="http://rymdcenter.se/rymdaret/partners-under-rymdaret/">Partners under Superrymdåret 2019</a>
</figcaption></figure>
```

I tried adding the following CSS.

```
.linktest a:link {
        color:white;
}
```

and

```
figcaption .linktest a:link {
        color:white;
}
```

Even just `a:link`, but it doesn't catch on. Am I missing something?

Comment: The `:link` selector is used to select unvisited links. If you have visited that link recently your styles will not show. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`figcaption` is a child of `.linktest` so your CSS is the wrong way around. The below should do the trick.

```
.linktest a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: this works. Although my links in the menu on the side become black on hoover now. Not sure if thats caused by this. Any idea what to put there to make them say white?

Comment: It shouldn't be. It looks like you have some styling in your `<head>` that is setting `.sidebar .widget a:hover { color: #050505; }`, and is overriding what you have in `style.css`. If you just remove that from your `<head>` it should revert to the orange.

Comment: It's not that easy to remove unfortunately. Wordpress is so damn convoluted. Can I force priority over the style somehow?

Comment: @Coolcrab I doubt it's Wordpress that's the issue. More likely the theme. You could try being more specific when adding your own CSS. For example, `.widget .tagcloud a:hover`, which should override the less-specific styling you currently have in the `<head>`.

Comment: @Coolcrab or you could use `!important`, but be wary that your code can get very messy if you use it too much.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly add without the link:

```
.linktest a{
        color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
figcaption .linktest a:link {
        color:white;
}
```

to

```
figcaption a:link {
    color:white;
```

}

`a` doesn't have parent with `linktest` class.

Hope this helps. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
.linktest figcaption a{color:#fff}
```

try using above code hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use

`.linktest a {
  color: white;
}`

instead of

`.linktest a:link {
  color:white;`
}